TypeScript - Invalid module name in augmentation, module '*.mp3' cannot be found
I got this error
Error: Cannot find module '../../../CONFIGS/OpenSupport.mp3'

I just googled it and found this solution. But this solution doesn't work...
I already tried
declare module "*.mp3";

declare module "*.mp3" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}

Both solutions do not work!
